# Coded UI Test - Set UI property not returning (hanging indefinitely)

Tags: user-interface, testing, methods, blocked

I am getting crazy with a problem that I found when executing a Visual Studio Coded UI Test.
The scenario is as follows.
I recorded a Coded UI Tests that do the following steps in a Web Application (Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011):

- Login into an application
- Navigate into a page
- On the page set the selected value of a html combobox

The test is able to do all those steps without a problem, even selecting the value in the combobox.
The web application have a piece of Javascript that is executed when the selected item changes.
if one of the values is selected then an alert message is presented to the user and the application will set the selected item to a default one!

The javascript code look like this:

```
    switch (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("status").getValue()) {
    case 3: //Authorised
        alert("Please use the method XPTO to update the record status to Authorised!");
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("status").setValue(1);
        Xrm.Page.getControl("tatus").setFocus(true);
        return false;
```

The UI Test method that is performing the change in the combobox is as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Select a value in the Status dropdown box
    /// </summary>
    public void SelectStatus()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlComboBox uIStatusComboBox = this.UIHttpsappWindow200.UIModuleUITEDocument5.UIWorkplaceDashboardsFrame.UIModuleUITEDocument.UIStatusComboBox;

        // Select 'Authorised' in 'Status' combo box
        uIStatusComboBox.SelectedItem = this.SelectStatus_SPParams.UIStatusComboBoxSelectedItem;

    }
```

The test method is able to change the value in the combobox, and an alert message is displayed to the user. However this part of the code `uIStatusComboBox.SelectedItem = this.SelectStatus_SPParams.UIStatusComboBoxSelectedItem;`
 never returns and the test just hangs there until it timeouts!

I have no ideia how to work arround this issue! I was thinking that maybe the problem could be in the fact that we have javascript code that is executed after the alert is displayed to the user. I changed the JS so that the alert message is the last thing to be displayed but it also didn´t help!

I also noticed that if I click Ok on the alert message the test Pass!

If I select other value that dont trigger any JS the test also Pass!

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

---

Edit 1:

I noticed another thing, I can use the BrowserWindow object to send a JS script to the browser. If I try to create an alert message the call also gets blocked until I click on the Ok button, on the alert!

```
BrowserWindow bw = BrowserWindow.Locate("My window");
bw.ExecuteScript("alert('This is just a simple alert.');");
```

The ExecuteScript statement also gets blocked until I click on the OK button!
This seems very very strange!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a workaround.
I was googling to find anything that could help me with this issue and I end up finding this question on StackOverflow [Coded ui test - Select an item from a combobox without using mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808271/coded-ui-test-select-an-item-from-a-combobox-without-using-mouse-coordinates)

I try to select the same item in the Dropdown without using the "SelectedItem" property of the HtmlComboBox element.
I try to use the keyboard to select the element in the dropdown box, first I click on the Dropdown and then I use the Down key and Enter key to select the element that I want:

```
public void SelectStatus_SP(string SelectedItem)
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlComboBox uIStatusComboBox = this.UIHttpsappWindow200.UIpopupUITEDocument5.UIWorkplaceDashboardsFrame.UIpopupUITEDocument.UIStatusComboBox;
        #endregion

        Mouse.Click(uIStatusComboBox);
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIStatusComboBox, "{Down}{Down}{Enter}", ModifierKeys.None);
    }
```

In my case the element that I want to select is the 3rd one, so I go down 2 times and then hit enter on the element I want to select.

This workaround is not so good because if the element changes position I will select the worng one! But this was the only way I got for the test not to be stock in that part!

I wonder if anyone had a similar issue. Because to me this seems like a bug in the Coded UI Test engine, It doesn´t make any scence for the test to be stocked while the alert is not closed!